# window fails to initiate when specifying a custom class name registered with RegisterClass to CreateWindowEx but only the second time I do it

Tags: c++, winapi, createwindowex, registerclass

I'm creating a window that's supposed to contain buttons.
When I create the first window (the container) I use a `WNDCLASS` to specify a `WindowProc` callback function to `lpfnWndProc` and it works as intended. When I do it the second time with a window, specifying a callback used to detect when the button is clicked, it doesn't work; the `CreateWindowEx` call there returns NULL (comment below shows where).

When I don't create `WNDCLAS wB` below and specify some other valid `lpClassName` to `CreateWindowEx` instead, such as `Button` it works fine.

### code used

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:wWinMainCRTStartup")

#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

HWND button;

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                                  LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow) {
  WNDCLASS wc = {};

  wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.lpszClassName = L"textedit";

  RegisterClass(&wc);

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
      0, wc.lpszClassName, L"textedit", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,

      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 340, 240, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
  if (hwnd == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, L"Edit", L"id here",
                                 WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 94, 20, 140,
                                 40, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
  // if I leave wcB unused/remove it and
  // specify L"Button" as the lpClassName to CreateWindowEx below, the button displays

  WNDCLASS wcB = {};

  wcB.lpfnWndProc = ButtonWindowProc;
  wcB.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcB.lpszClassName = L"modify";

  RegisterClass(&wcB);

  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
  // doing the exact same thing I did when creating the first window
  // but it fails to create the window

  HWND hButton =
      CreateWindowEx(0L, L"modify", L"modify", BS_FLAT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                      94, 70, 140, 50, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
  ShowWindow(hButton, nCmdShow);

  // here hButton is NULL     <----------------------

  if (hButton == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  MSG msg = {};
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                                  LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;

    case BN_CLICKED:
         std::cout << "clicked";
    case WM_PAINT:
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      return 0;
  }

  return 0;
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

`GetLastError()` returns 1400, but I don't understand how the handle `hwnd` could possible be invalid because as I mentioned before, when I just change the `lpClassName` I pass to `CreateWindowEx`, it works without errors.

I would appreciate any help in finding out why the window (the HWND of which is `hButton`) does not initiate, and possible workarounds.

Comment: `ButtonWindowProc` returns 0 for all messages it doesn't handle, and doesn't pass them to `DefWindowProc`. In particular, it returns 0 in response to [`WM_NCCREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate), which is a signal that the window creation has failed. You probably didn't mean to put `return 0;` right before `return DefWindowProc(...);`

Comment: Good catch. I removed that but it seems to make the button disappear altogether (does not happen when I use L"Button" as the lpClassName).

Comment: I've noticed the button **is** present however, just invisible for some reason.  `ButtonWindowProc` logs messages (I call `std::cout` at the start of the definition) when I hover over that area where the button is supposed to be.

Comment: `(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1)` is only meaningful in `WNDCLASS::hbrBackground`. It's not generally a valid brush handle. Most likely, `FillRect` call fails.

Comment: You're right, `FillRect` does fail. When I remove it though it still is invisible. Can you point me in the right direction for a a replacement to that?

Comment: It's invisible because it doesn't paint anything in `WM_PAINT`. What did you expect to see? `DefWindowProc` paints it with the background brush (in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND`), which happens to be the same color as the parent window's background brush.

Comment: I think you can pass the syscolor index to FillRect, that's not the problem, the problem is you're painting COLOR_WINDOW for the button over the top of COLOR_WINDOW for the parent window.

Comment: So `FillRect` fails so I change that to not paint anything, which of course leaves it invisible. Naturally I thought to fix that and paint a specific color myself since I can't have it take a default color apparently, and now the color gets painted over the text in the window as well as the button so the text isn't visible either. If I can't leave it alone and I can't paint it myself to allow some text to appear, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: It is perhaps also worth noting that if I go this route (register my own class) the cursor does not even become a pointer when hovering on top of the button, as if the button isn't meant to be clicked at all

Comment: You are registering a window class whose `hCursor` member is `NULL`. Consult the documentation to learn about the consequences.

Comment: Drawing order is important. see [Child Window Update Region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/child-window-update-region).

Comment: made the necessary fixes here and it is visible and the hCursor has been set appropriately,

Comment: ideally I would be able to have my own `lpfnWndProc` so I can detect messages for windows of predefined system classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem in the title was solved by the  comment by Igor Tandetnik:

> ButtonWindowProc returns 0 for all messages it doesn't handle, and doesn't pass them to DefWindowProc. In particular, it returns 0 in response to WM_NCCREATE, which is a signal that the window creation has failed. You probably didn't mean to put return 0; right before return DefWindowProc(...);

After fixing that, the window was created but was invisible.
To fix that I used `FillRect` with a valid brush handle

```cpp
 SetDCBrushColor(hdc, bkcolor);
 SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(187, 189, 189));
 FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
```

To detect left mouse button clicks you need to check for the [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) message.